# openldap configuration on solaris 10

Tags: openldap

While installing openldap, I am getting below error and compilation stops, please advice.

```
cc -g -I../../../include -I../../../include -I.. -I./.. -I./../../../libraries/liblmdb -I/sites/bdb/include -c ./../../../libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c -o mdb.o
"./../../../libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c", line 4625: warning: implicit function declaration: pthread_mutexattr_setrobust
"./../../../libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c", line 4625: undefined symbol: PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST
"./../../../libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c", line 10002: warning: implicit function declaration: pthread_mutex_consistent
cc: acomp failed for ./../../../libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c
Makefile:309: recipe for target 'mdb.lo' failed
gmake[3]: *** [mdb.lo] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/sites/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd/back-mdb'
Makefile:541: recipe for target '.backend' failed
gmake[2]: *** [.backend] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/sites/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd'
Makefile:291: recipe for target 'all-common' failed
gmake[1]: *** [all-common] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/sites/openldap-2.4.44/servers'
Makefile:312: recipe for target 'all-common' failed
gmake: *** [all-common] Error 1
[/sites/openldap-2.4.44]
```

I have configured bdb as below:

```
cd /sites/db-4.8.30/build_unix/
../dist/configure --prefix=/sites/bdb
make
make install
```

Installing openldap:

```
cd openldap-2.4.44/
./configure --prefix=/sites/openldap --enable-dynamic --enable-spasswd --enable-slapd  --enable-mdb --enable-monitor
make depend
make all
```

I am getting above error at last step.

Below is the env

```
atg@lynntools01$ uname -a
SunOS lynntools01 5.10 Generic_150400-30 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

Comment: i need mdb as backend, installed bdb because openldap has dependencies on it.

Comment: it looks like it is the problem for all db(bdb, mdb etc) as same error i got for bdb as backend as well.